# responsive Todo List - how to deal with rem in tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, checkbox, responsive

As a react exercice I am trying to implement a todo list app with react.

The todo list is almost done, but for some reasons, i want it to display nicely also on mobile and fit the content accordingly to the screen size.

My problem is my checkboxes are sized with Rems - 6 rems in height and width. But in mobile devices, rems are not equivalent to their original size and the width of my checkboxes shrinks.

Do you have any idea to overcome this resizing ? See screen captures below

| Large | Mobile |
| --- | --- |
| [image: todo list View1] | [[image: todo list View2] |

you can see the code of the todo List at https://github.com/freddy-turtle/todo-list

the code of the checkboxes is

```
<input
          type="checkbox"
          name="checked-demo"
          className="form-tick appearance-none flex-initial bg-white bg-check h-6 w-6 min-w-6 border border-gray-300 rounded-md checked:bg-blue-500 checked:border-transparent focus:outline-none"
        />
```

Comment: why don't you have fixed width, height in pixels ?

Comment: tailwind by default size element with rems - you cannot use pixels as units without making pixels as default units for your entire page

Comment: You certainly can use px units in Tailwind. With JIT mode you can juse do `h-[40px]` and if you're not using JIT you can extend the theme spacing config in `tailwind.config.js` as shown in this play example https://play.tailwindcss.com/2EkfPjPhg5

Comment: To be clear I don't think using px units is the right answer here. It looks like your elements are being smooshed on mobile because you have 2 checkboxes where there should be one. Maybe you started making a mobile version and forgot to hide the desktop, but the middle checkbox in the mobile screenshot is evidence that it's not your sizing that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've come to the final solution as :

- don't set pixels as your default unit in tailwind. This would break some design by default in tailwind and you will loose the ability to use commonly rems
- instead, define some customs classes or "utility" with the `@layer` syntax in postcss (which is the preprocessor behind tailwind).
- In our case, define a width equal to 24px boils down to

  @layer utilities {
  .w-24px {
  width: 24px;
  min-width: 24px;
  }
  }

and use it as additional in your html.

Final capture :
[image: screen capture]